# Robot Framework' Playwright, trying to get list of all the href values on a page, then verify they're valid

Tags: robotframework, href, playwright

Using Robot Framework's Playwright I am trying to get elements from a page, their href value, like href='http://www.mywebpage.com/customer/create/signup.html' and put them into a list.

From there I will ultimately try to compare if each element is similar to the substring of my base URL (which should be contained in each href link value), and then if each link returns a 200 response.

So far my code does get a list of elements(this is good), but each element looks something like this, "element=5cf0c691-41b1-4a3e-9347-d1a2bf0a48b8" instead of a URL ... I will want to query if each list element is similar to a base URL, so I want each element to be the href URL.

So, how can I evaluate what gets put into the list ${element_href} as the equivalent href URL, instead of something like "element=5cf0c691..." which I am currently getting?

```
Broken links test
    ${element_list}=        browser.get elements    xpath=//*[starts-with(@href, 'http://')]    #same as above that finds 45 elements.
    Log     ${element_list}

Create Session    testing    ${BASE_URL}
FOR    ${element_href}    IN    @{element_list}    #get text gets same as without it.
    ${uri}=    Remove String    ${element_href}    ${BASE_URL}
    ${contains_base_url}=    Evaluate     "${BASE_URL}" in "${element_href}"

    ${response}=    Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Get Request    testing    ${uri}
    Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Should Be Equal As Strings     ${response.status_code}    200
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to getting page href URL's into a list. Still struggling to compare each list item with the base URL, and then check if they navigate with a 200 response - but this progress effectively answers specifically what I asked above, how to gather elements on the page, namely the href attribute values, and into a list. The 4 commented lines before "END" are what I'm trying to get to work next, so far unsuccessfully; that said, here is the code:

```
Broken links test
    ${element_list}=     get elements     xpath=//a[@href]     #ORIGINAL

    Create Session    testing    ${BASE_URL}
    @{element_attribute_list}=    Create List
    FOR    ${element_href}    IN    @{element_list}    #get text gets same as without it.
    ${element_attribute}=    get attribute  ${element_href}     href
    Append To List    ${element_attribute_list}   ${element_attribute}
#        ${uri}=    Remove String    ${element_attribute_list}    ${BASE_URL}
#        ${contains_base_url}=    Evaluate     "${BASE_URL}" in "${element_attribute_list}"
#        ${response}=    Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Get Request    testing    ${uri}
#        Run Keyword If    ${contains_base_url}    Should Be Equal As Strings     ${response.status_code}    200
    END
```

RESULTS HERE - they're not perfect, but code is appending to list each href, or so it appears:

```
KEYWORD Collections . Append To List ${element_attribute_list}, ${element_attribute}
Documentation:  
Adds values to the end of list.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20220130 22:41:18.685 / 20220130 22:41:18.685 / 00:00:00.000
22:41:18.685    TRACE   Arguments: [ ['http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/',
 '#',
 'http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/customer/account/create/',
 'http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/customer/account/login/',
 'http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/checkout/cart/',
 '/courses.html',
 '#',
 'http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/certification-courses/#swm'] | 'http://dev.mysite.net/PAP-4414/certification-courses/#dwc' ]   
22:41:18.685    TRACE   Return: None
```

Any additional thoughts are welcome! I appreciate the 10 Views, although no comments so far.